# Angular app can't find ng-template tpl.html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a simple angular `TabCtrl` that loads different template files.  I include the template files themselves as such:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="summary.tpl.html">
  // Actual template elements
</script>
```

Inside the `ng-app` and on the same page as the `TabCtrl`.  However, the templates are not loading on page load or when a tab is clicked.  I pretty much followed this JSFiddle exactly (http://jsfiddle.net/eRGT8/162/)... what am I doing wrong?

If you can't help me without me posting more code, I'll do so.

EDIT:  More code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
          ng-class="{active_tab:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
          ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="tab-icon">
            <i ng-class="tab.icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-label">{{tab.label}}</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="dashboard" ng-include="activeTab"></div>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="summary.tpl.html">
        HI
      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="downloads.tpl.html">

      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="ads.tpl.html">

      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="landing.tpl.html">

      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="retargeted.tpl.html">

      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** JS File

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
      label: 'one',
      icon: 'one',
      url: 'summary.tpl.html'
    }, {
      label: 'two',
      icon: 'two',
      url: 'downloads.tpl.html'
    }, {
      label: 'three',
      icon: 'three',
      url: 'ads.tpl.html'
    }, {
      label: 'four',
      icon: 'four',
      url: 'landing.tpl.html'
    }, {
      label: 'five',
      icon: 'five',
      url: 'retargeted.tpl.html'
  }];

  $scope.activeTab = 'summary.tpl.html';

  $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.activeTab = tab.url;
  }

  $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.activeTab;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle works for me.

Comment: I know, the JSFiddle works great.  I copied it on my own website, pretty much line for line, and it isn't loading the templates.

Comment: it looks like we will need you to post more code.

Comment: Not sure, it should be working... can't think of a reason why it wouldn't.  This may be a dumb question - are all your tags closed? is TabCtrl and ng-app set correctly?  Are your ng-templates within the element that has the ng-app?

Comment: Can you post the js file that defines TabsCtrl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ng-include="activeTab"` it's defined outside the scope of `TabsCtrl` in `ng-controller="TabsCtrl"`.

Try to add it to the div `id="wrapper"`.

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
```

The element

`<div class="dashboard" ng-include="activeTab">`

needs to be **inside** the TabsCtrl, then they can communicate to each other.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Another (but not so recommended way) is to add the variable to the **$rootScope** and pass it to the Controller.

For example:

> `myApp
>     .controller('TabsCtrl', 
>         ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {`
>
> ```
>        ...
>
>        $rootScope.activeTab = 'summary.tpl.html';
> ```

In this case, the `activeTab` will be available in the entire `ng-app="myApp"` scope.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer and for keeping improving your answer, even after it's been accepted. I really like that.

Comment: Thanks, I like too, because help me to prevent this simple problems that make we lost hours to find it..